# How to populate data collection present in below format in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Data to be fetched from Atlas
contains 3 documents (Schema-categorySchema), each document stores an array of objectIds of another document (Schema-subCategorySchema)

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f055f4b00bde224583e35cf"},"name":"cat1","sub_categories":[],"__v":0}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f055f5700bde224583e35d0"},"name":"cat2","sub_categories":[{"_id":{"$oid":"5f05a8633ca5a141d45c2dee"},"subcatergory_id":{"$oid":"5f05a8633ca5a141d45c2ded"}},{"_id":{"$oid":"5f05ab45f69e0435b81ff560"},"subcatergory_id":{"$oid":"5f05ab44f69e0435b81ff55f"}}],"__v":2}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f058108f14eba3aa067e7a0"},"name":"Veg1","sub_categories":[],"__v":0}
```

Schema is mentioned below for above data.

```
const categorySchema = new Schema({ name: { type: String, required: true, }, sub_categories: [ { subcatergory_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "SubCategory", }, }, ], });
```

I am expecting to populate the 3 documents, along with data that is referred by array of ObjectId.
How to write the query for the getting output based mentioned model?

I have written a query like below but it fails.

```
exports.getCategoryList = (req, res, next) => {  
    Category.find().then((categories) => {       
        console.log(categories.sub_categories); 
        if (categories) {
            res.json({ "Category List": categories.sub_categories });
        } else {
            res.send("Empty Category List");
        }
    }).catch((err) => res.send("error:" + err));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can populate this way:

```
Category.find()
       .populate('sub_categories._id sub_categories.subcatergory_id')
       .then((categories) => {       
        console.log(categories.sub_categories); 
        if (categories) {
            res.json({ "Category List": categories.sub_categories });
        } else {
            res.send("Empty Category List");
        }
    }).catch((err) => res.send("error:" + err));
```

**OR**

```
Category.find()
        .populate('sub_categories._id')
        .populate('sub_categories.subcatergory_id')
        .then((categories) => {       
        console.log(categories.sub_categories); 
        if (categories) {
            res.json({ "Category List": categories.sub_categories });
        } else {
            res.send("Empty Category List");
        }
    }).catch((err) => res.send("error:" + err));
```

Comment: @Avinash Boddu Welcome.